# saving results of a statistical test to one file using apply over a data frame in R

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to run statistical tests over each column of a data frame and save the results to a file.  I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to do this using apply instead of a for loop?   and
2. Can I save the results of all the tests to a single file?

Given a toy data frame:

```
DataFrame <- data.frame(Treatment= rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 6),
             A=sample(1:100, 18), 
             B=sample(1:100, 18), 
             C=sample(1:100, 18))
```

So far I've done this, which runs the tests I want (in this case pairwise t tests, but I'm doing the same thing with other tests), but saves the results of each to a separate file:

```
library(MASS)
Col_pairwise.t.test <- function(data.frame){DataFrame <- data.frame
 for (i in 2:length(DataFrame)){
   i_test <- pairwise.t.test(DataFrame[ ,i], DataFrame$Treatment, p.adj = "none")

   write.matrix(i_test$p.value, file = paste(colnames(DataFrame[i]), 
     +   "_t_test.txt", sep = ""), sep="\t")
}}
Col_pairwise.t.test(DataFrame)
```

I can use apply instead of a for loop to run the tests, but don't know how to save the p-values to a file when I do this:

```
apply(DataFrame[ , 2:4], 2, pairwise.t.test, g=DataFrame$Treatment, p.adj = "none")
```

I'm still quite new to R, and any help would be much appreciated!  I'm sure there's a much nicer way to do what I'm already doing with apply instead of a for loop, and I know there must be a way to store all the results of the t tests and write them to a file at the end, I just don't know what it is.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `apply`, you can use `ldply`from `plyr` to convert it into a `data.frame` and store the individual `p.value` matrices as a merged `p.value` data.frame as follows:

```
w <- apply(DataFrame[ , 2:4], 2, pairwise.t.test, g=DataFrame$Treatment, p.adj = "none")
require(plyr)
out <- ldply(w, function(x) x$p.value)

#   .id          A          B
# 1   A 0.29299651         NA
# 2   A 0.22354405 0.03227708
# 3   B 0.02434804         NA
# 4   B 0.73621775 0.04736056
# 5   C 0.92880561         NA
# 6   C 0.09587581 0.11248443
```

Now, you can write this to file using

```
write.table(out, "file.txt", quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=T)
```

The first column `.id` the comparison and the 2nd and the 3rd columns are the corresponding p-value matrix you obtained.

PS: Please don't use `data.frame` (or even `DataFrame`) as names for your objects. There is an inbuilt function called `data.frame` that directly clashes with it and it is not good programming practice. Just for example, I'd change your function (which you don't need anymore) as follows:

```
library(MASS)
Col_pairwise.t.test <- function(d) {
    for (i in 2:length(d)) {
        i_test <- pairwise.t.test(d[ ,i], d$Treatment, p.adj = "none")
        write.matrix(i_test$p.value, 
            file = paste(colnames(d[i]), "_t_test.txt", sep = ""), sep="\t")
    }
}
Col_pairwise.t.test(df)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  That's exactly what I was seeking.  My real data frame isn't called "DataFrame," I just thought that might be less confusing than "df," which is what folks often use, since "df" is also an inbuilt function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous function inside the apply loop that returns the p-values from the test instead of the entire test.  Like so...

```
pvals = apply(DataFrame[, 2:4], 2, function(x){
            pairwise.t.test(x=x, g=DataFrame$Treatment, p.adj = "none")$p.value
        })
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's lovely, as I don't even have to play with the results to get them into the same layout/form as the original data frame.  Unlike R, I like my data wide rather than long!